# Deserialize a single object

Tags: java

I want to serialize and deserialize an object. I thought it would be easier but I seem to do something wrong...
I have a `Cat class` with some properties. I serialized the `Cat` like this:

```java
Cat cat = new Cat("SerializedCat",Gender.Male,"");
try{
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("employee.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
    out.writeObject(cat);
    out.close();
    fileOut.close();
    System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in employee.ser");
}catch(IOException i){
    i.printStackTrace();
}
```

In another form, I try to deserialize it, but I get the following error :

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: classes.Cat; no valid constructor
```

The way I deserialize the object

```java
try {
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("employee.ser");
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
    deserializedCat = (Cat) in.readObject();
    in.close();
    fileIn.close();
} catch (IOException i) {
    i.printStackTrace();
    return;
} catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
    System.out.println("Employee class not found");
    c.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

I do have implemented Serializable to my `Cat class`. This is my `Cat class`:

```java
package classes;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Cat extends Animal implements Serializable {
    private String badHabits;
    private double price;

    public Cat(String name, Gender gender , String badHabits) {
        super(name,gender);

        this.badHabits = badHabits;
        calculatePrice();
    }

    public void calculatePrice(){
        this.price = Math.max(350 - (badHabits.length() * 20), 35);
    }

    public String getBadHabits() {
        return badHabits;
    }
    public void setBadHabits(String badhabits){this.badHabits = badhabits;}

    public String toString(){
        return "Bad habits: " + badHabits;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

Comment: make `Animal` serializable

Answer (score -1):

```
Use ObjectMapper class for serailizatin/ deserialization.
 - readValue() method to deserialize
 - writeValue() to serialize
```

eg.
To serialize:

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   mapper.writeValue(new File("file-path-here"), catObject);
```

To deserialize:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Cat cat = mapper.readValue(new File("file-path-here"), Cat.class);
```

Comment: How do I use the objectmapper class?

Comment: @jantjesmith added example in the answer

Comment: @jantjesmith You dont. You asked "how do I use built in java serialization properly". The answer goes "use something else". Sure, that is possible, but not a valid answer here, as you ask about a very specific problem with *your* code.

Comment: @GhostCat, question only says, that user wants to serialize and deserialize the object. Specifies nothing about restricting only to java-built-in features. Hence, i believe it's a valid answer.

Comment: He shows all "default java serialization" code. He asks about a typical "default java serialization" coding error, and the corresponding runtime error. That is like going "I want to use my longbow to hit that target, but the arrow keeps breaking, how do I fix that", and you come in "use a shotgun".

Comment: It already worked! Thanks, I had to make Animal Serializable

Comment: Suggesting alternatives is fine. But then say so in your answer. You claim that your content *answers* the question. It doesn't. It is suggesting to avoid that error, by doing something really different. A solution that comes with its own sets of requirements and potential issues. I write "non answers" myself frequently. But I openly say so. And note: the OP has made it very clear with his comment here that your answer was no help to him. He was looking how to FIX his problem, not how to replace his solution with something completely different.

Comment: Fair. Thanks for explaination.